# North Pole Right Ascension/Declination to axial tilt conversion

Tags: planet

Wikipedia , on several asteroid articles, claims that right ascension and declination of the North Pole can give you the axial tilt of the object. What formula is used to convert these 2 values into the axial tilt? (Ceres, for example, has an R.A. Of 291 degrees and a declination of 59 degrees; its axial tilt is approximately 3 degrees. How is this figured?

Comment: You measure the distance from the body's north pole to the ecliptic north pole: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic_pole

Comment: Could you show how this is done?

Comment: Being too lazy to answer that <G>, I will point out that the Wikipedia Ceres article gives an RA of 29.41 degrees, a declination of 66.79 degrees, and an inclination of 10.593 degrees to the ecliptic. Could you source your data or perhaps you're thinking of another dwarf planet?

Comment: No I saw it before

Comment: OK, it's on the wikipedia page, but it's followed by "Dawn would later determine that the axis points in a different direction."

Comment: I saw the values as different a long time ago and I saw it for Ceres.maybe I was wrong. But I don't know how it's done and I really want to, mathematically.

Comment: OK, it turns out I misread your question anyway. Are you sure you don't mean "inclination to the ecliptic" (which you can compute from the direction of the north pole) instead of "axial tilt", which is different?

Comment: http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/what-is-the-axial-tilt-of-a-planet-measured-relative-to explains the difference.

Comment: I just want to know how the axial tilt is determined via the right ascension and declination, as shown in multiple Wikipedia articles on asteroids, such as Pallas and Eunomia. Im not wanting to know specifically this object, but for example, how did these 2 numbers reveal Ceres' axial tilt to be 3 degrees? What math can be done to show this?

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong, but may help someone find the right answer:

You can convert right ascension and declination to a 3 dimensional 
unit vector in the J2000.0 ICRF reference frame using the standard 
formula for converting spherical coordinates to rectangular 
coordinates and using a radius of 1:

`{Cos[dec] Cos[ra], Cos[dec] Sin[ra], Sin[dec]}`

The ra and dec of the north ecliptic pole is ra,dec of 
`{270, 66.5607083333}` per Wikipedia, so the unit vector representing 
the north ecliptic pole is:

`{0, -0.3977771648286046, 0.9174820582119942}`

As it turns out, there is conflicting data for Ceres, perhaps because 
of the semi-recent DAWN flyby.

Instead, I'll use Vesta, where wikipedia explicitly states (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4_Vesta#Rotation):

`north pole pointing in the direction of right ascension 20 h 32 min, 
declination +48 [... which] gives an axial tilt of 29 [degrees]`

Converting to degrees, Vesta's north pole's ra,dec is 
`{308,48}`. Using the formula above to find the unit vector, we get:

`{0.411957936296447, -0.527282113378167, 0.743144825477394}`

If we take the dot product of two vectors and divide by the product of 
their lengths, we get the cosine of the angle between them. In this 
case, both vectors have length 1, and the dot product is `0.891563` 
whose arc-cosine is right around 27 degrees.

So, *if* Vesta's orbit were the same plane as Earth's orbit, the axial 
tilt would be 27 degrees.

However, since Vesta's orbit is inclined 7.14043 degrees to the 
ecliptic, this answer is incorrect.

I don't think you can find the correct answer without using Vesta's 
inclination and the longitude of its ascending node.

Both of these values are known, but I can't figure out how to use them 
to get the correct asnwer.