# How was the axial tilt of planets measured?

Tags: planet, rotation, observational-astronomy

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_tilt#Solar_System_bodies gives the axial tilt of all planets with two decimal precision, but how and when were they measured so precisely ?

I guess it's "easy" for Mars, Jupiter and Saturn (thanks to the rings ?) but how was it measured for Venus under its clouds, or Uranus + Neptune that are so far away ?

Links to scientific publications would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can identify features in Venus' clouds as well as in the atmospheres of the other planets even with amateur equipment - and track them if you get a long enough sequence. Their rotation axis gives the tilt.

Comment: With Venus you can also do earth-based radar measurements of the solid surface (or could until Arecibo crashed). And of course everything can be measured in-situ by orbiters.

Comment: The gas giants have powerful magnetospheres that can be observed by radio astronomy.  Though in the case of Uranus, it isn't aligned with the spin axis, hehe: https://physicsworld.com/a/nightmare-geometry-of-uranus-creates-tumbling-magnetosphere/ . Luckily Uranus also has observable rings.

Comment: See: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/what-is-the-axial-tilt-of-a-planet-measured-relative-to

Comment: The values are available with greater than two decimals of precision on these sub-pages: https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/planetfact.html - found by following the reference on Wikipedia.